# Angular5 PWA doesn't refresh (Service Workers)

Tags: angular-cli, service-worker, angular5, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm developing an app with angular5, using service workers via the ng-cli, but I realized that after the first time the app shell loads, it doesn't refresh. How can I push new file versions to my app after build it with `ng build`?. I could directly rewrite the sw.js manually, but as it is generated via the cli, I don't like to affect anything I don't know what is for.

I'm looking for this answer all day, but as service workers are new for the 1.6 version of the ng-cli, I have not found any.

I even found a thread similar thread for angular 4 and a unofficial service workers implementation before ng-cli 1.6, but I don't trust in that approach since it is not official, so I would like to know if you guys could help me find a way to control the way it installs the shell and looks for new versions.

Thank you

Comment: Hi @judasane, did you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I'll post it as an answer, Hope to help you.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what worked for me.
This helps the browser detect there is a new version of the app.

**App.component.ts:**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {    
      
      constructor(public updates:SwUpdate) {
        updates.available.subscribe(event => {
          console.log('current version is', event.current);
          console.log('available version is', event.available);
        });
        updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
          console.log('old version was', event.previous);
          console.log('new version is', event.current);
        });
    
        updates.available.subscribe(event => {
            updates.activateUpdate().then(() => this.updateApp());
        });
       }
      
       updateApp(){
        document.location.reload();
        console.log("The app is updating right now");
    
       }
}
```

And

**ngsw.json:**

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "Your app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "lazy",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "lazy",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ],
        "urls":[
          "https://urlsyouwanttocachefrom.com/**",
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, every time the app is updated, the browser will autoreload.

Comment: Not sure how it worked for you. But it did not work for me. Actually I'm expecting my application to get auto-reload when new build deployed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a good way of testing how this would work? I'm kind of trusting your code to work, but I'm not sure how I could see for myself whether it works. Also what about outdated versions? Will they auto update as well or only versions after this?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer from judasane, I've managed to use the built-in `SwUpdate` class to manually check for updates each time the app is loaded (only showing a loading indicator at this point), and reload it when an update can be applied, hence making sure that when someone opens the app, it's always the latest version.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  updateChecked = false;
  updateAvailable = false;
  
  // In your template, use this value to show a loading indicator while we are
  // waiting for updates. (You can also use it to hide the rest of the UI if
  // you want to prevent the old version from being used.)
  get waitingForUpdates() {
    return !this.updateChecked || this.updateAvailable;
  }

  constructor(private updates: SwUpdate) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.updates.available.subscribe(() => {
      // Keep the loading indicator active while we reload the page
      this.updateAvailable = true;
      window.location.reload();
    });
    if (this.updates.isEnabled) {
      // This promise will return when the update check is completed,
      // and if an update is available, it will also wait for the update
      // to be downloaded (at which point it calls our callback above and
      // we just need to reload the page to apply it).
      await this.updates.checkForUpdate();
    } else {
      console.log('Service worker updates are disabled.');
    }
    // The update check is done (or service workers are disabled), now
    // we can take the loading indicator down (unless we need to apply an
    // update, but in that case, we have already set this.updateAvailable
    // to true by this point, which keeps the loading indicator active).
    this.updateChecked = true;
  }
}
```